# how to get values from object array in javascript with condition

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do something complex thing with array. I have array

```
   ORGANIZATIONS = [
    {

        "MAINID": "INAP1650001",
        "Status": "Approved"
    },
    {
        "MAINID": "INAP1650002",
        "Status": "Pending"
    },
    {
     "MAINID": "INAP1650003",
      "Status": "Approved"
    },
    {
      "MAINID": "INAP1650004",
         "Status": "Pending"
    },
    {
     "MAINID": "INAP1650005",
     "Status": "Approved"
    }
]
```

So I am trying to get all "MAINID" which status is "Approved" and want to create array of MAINID like `MAINID_Array = [INAP1650001, INAP1650003,INAP1650005]`
Could anybody help me please as I have tried using below but its give me all MAINID

```
var status = ''
var MAINID = ''
var MAINID_array = []
let len = ORGANIZATIONS.length

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    Status = ORGANIZATIONS[i].STATUS;
    MAINID = ORGANIZATIONS[i].MAINID;

    console.log('STATUS', Status);
    console.log('MAINID', MAINID);

        console.log('Approve STATUS', Status);

        MAINID_array.push(MAINID);

}

console.log(MAINID_array)
```

Comment: var result=ORGANIZATIONS.filter(i=>i.Status==="Approved").map(m=>m.MAINID);

Comment: I thought the same like most folks using Filter & Map:
```const MAINID_Array = ORGANIZATIONS.filter(organization => organization['Status'] === 'Approved').map(approvedOrganization => approvedOrganization['MAINID']);```

but the answer provided by https://stackoverflow.com/a/64360006/7377537 Derek.W using reduce is the best neat solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), you can get the array of `MAINID` of which status is `Approved`.

```js
const input = [{
    "MAINID": "INAP1650001",
    "Status": "Approved"
  },
  {
    "MAINID": "INAP1650002",
    "Status": "Pending"
  },
  {
    "MAINID": "INAP1650003",
    "Status": "Approved"
  },
  {
    "MAINID": "INAP1650004",
    "Status": "Pending"
  },
  {
    "MAINID": "INAP1650005",
    "Status": "Approved"
  }
];

const result = input.reduce((acc, cur) => (cur.Status === 'Approved' ? [ ...acc, cur.MAINID] : acc), []);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use higher order functions like [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the organizations you want based on the `Status` property and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return the `MAINID` from each organization to create an array of `MAINID` strings.

```js
const ORGANIZATIONS = [{
    "MAINID": "INAP1650001",
    "Status": "Approved"
  },
  {
    "MAINID": "INAP1650002",
    "Status": "Pending"
  },
  {
    "MAINID": "INAP1650003",
    "Status": "Approved"
  },
  {
    "MAINID": "INAP1650004",
    "Status": "Pending"
  },
  {
    "MAINID": "INAP1650005",
    "Status": "Approved"
  }
];

const getApprovedOrganizations = organizations => organizations
  .filter(({ Status }) => Status === 'Approved')
  .map(({ MAINID }) => MAINID);
  
const MAINID_Array = getApprovedOrganizations(ORGANIZATIONS);
console.log(MAINID_Array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use map and filter to solve your problem.

```
const mainIds = ORGANIZATIONS.filter((item) => item.Status === 'Approved').map((item) => item.MAINID);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the single line answer:

```js
let ORGANIZATIONS = [
    {

        "MAINID": "INAP1650001",
        "Status": "Approved"
    },
    {
        "MAINID": "INAP1650002",
        "Status": "Pending"
    },
    {
     "MAINID": "INAP1650003",
      "Status": "Approved"
    },
    {
      "MAINID": "INAP1650004",
         "Status": "Pending"
    },
    {
     "MAINID": "INAP1650005",
     "Status": "Approved"
    }
]

let mainIdArray = ORGANIZATIONS.filter(x => x.Status === "Approved").map(x => x.MAINID);

console.log(mainIdArray);
```

Explanation:

```
.filter(x => x.Status === "Approved")
```

gets the organizations that `Status === "Approved"`.

```
.map(x => x.MAINID)
```

gets the `MAINID` field of each organization.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
const MAINID_array =[];
ORGANIZATIONS.forEach(element =>{
       if (element['Status'] === "Approved"){
           MAINID_array.push(element['MAINID']);
       }  
})
```